# HTML5 Files and FileLists path

Tags: javascript, file, html

I am wondering where the file path is stored in a File object in HTML javascript.

I used the Webkit DevTools and got this:

```
FileList
0: File
    fileName: "script.js"
    fileSize: 71268
    name: "script.js"
    size: 71268
    type: "application/x-javascript"
    __proto__: File
length: 1
__proto__: FileList
```

The file name, size and types are there(anyone knows why name and size have 2 variables), but the path is not.

Is there any way to find path of the file, and if not, how does the browser and javascript read the file(such as POST methods & determining the type and size)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can read in the [WHATWG HTML spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/#file-upload-state-%28type=file%29),

> [f]or historical reasons, the [value](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/#dom-input-value)
>   IDL attribute prefixes the filename
>   with the string "C:\fakepath\". Some
>   legacy user agents actually included
>   the full path (which was a security
>   vulnerability).

Reading on on [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File#Properties), we can see that Mozilla's implementation of the File object has a (non-standard) property named `mozFullPath`, containing

> [t]he full path of the referenced
>   file; available only to code with
>   UniversalFileRead privileges in
>   chrome.

That page also answers your question about the redundant data in the File object: properties `fileName` and `fileSize` are deprecated. Also look at W3C's [File API Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#file), where those are not mentioned.

To answer the second part of your question:

> if not, how does the browser and
>   JavaScript read the file (such as POST
>   methods & determining the type and
>   size)?

Of course, internally the complete file path can be accessed (and is in several browsers shown to the user), but it's not accessible to JavaScript scripts running in a web page.

By the way, a few years ago there was a discussion about this on the [WHATWG mailing list](http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2008-March/thread.html#14225).